# Assigning user input values to allocated memory

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, malloc, variable-assignment

The idea behind the program is to declare a data structure for student information, then have the user input information into each field of the data structure for an inputted amount of students. My issue is the program stops working when I input the first name. What is wrong? Thank you for your time.

```
//Inclusion of necessary header files
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Data structure declaration
struct student{
char firstName[20];
char lastName[20];
char id[10];
char gender;
int age;
double gpa;
};

//Function prototypes
void readStudentsInformation(struct student *, int size); 
void outputStudents(struct student *, int size);
double averageGPA(struct student *, int size);
void sortByLastName(struct student *, int size);
void sortByGPA(struct student *, int size);


//Entry point
int main()
{
    //Variable delcaration
    int size;
    struct student *ptr;
    //Input prompt and function
    printf("How many students?\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &size);

    //Allocation memory for struct student times the number of students and assigning it to a struct student pointer for external function modification
    ptr = (struct student*)malloc(sizeof(struct student)*size);

    //readStudentsInformation Function call
    readStudentsInformation(ptr, size);

    //Exit sequence
    return 0;
}

//This functions reads the information for all the students from the keyboard, taking the class size through the pointer method and struct student from main
void readStudentsInformation(struct student *ptr, int size) 
{
    //For loop controller declaration
    int i;
    //Function message
    printf("Student Information Form\n");
    //This for loop increments the "index" of each students info location where user input is stored
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        //Each field has it's appropriate input limit
        printf("Please enter Student %d's First Name(20 characters).\n", i+1);
        scanf_s("%20s", ptr[i].firstName);
        printf("Please enter Student %d's Last Name(20 characters).\n", i+1);       
        scanf_s("%20s", ptr[i].lastName);                                   
        printf("Please enter Student %d's ID(10 characters).\n",i+1);               
        scanf_s("%10s", ptr[i].id);
        printf("Please enter Student %d's gender(M/F).\n",i+1);
        scanf_s("%c", ptr[i].gender);
        printf("Please enter Student %d's age.\n",i+1);
        scanf_s("%3d", ptr[i].age);   //Only 3 digits can be put in at a time
        printf("Please enter Student %d's GPA.\n", i+1);
        scanf_s("%.1lf", ptr[i].gpa);   //From the lab it can be seen that no more than one decimal place is featured, so the same is done here
    }

    //Exit to main
    return;
}
```

Comment: I have adjusted the scanf_s's, however the program still seems to crash. I don't feel it is proper addressing. What if I declared an array of type struct student and established its array size to the user input?

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
scanf_s("%20s", ptr[i].firstName);
```

to read first name. `ptr+i` will give you `student` structure. You want to store data in the structure member.

Change your other `scanf`s as well for this.

Comment: No, missing size parameter. "The fscanf_s function is equivalent to fscanf except that the c, s, and [ conversion specifiers apply to a pair of arguments ..."

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
scanf("%s",ptr[i].firstName);
```

and so on for the rest of the structure members in your scanf()'s.

Answer (score 0):

change `scanf_s` to `scanf` and change this block as follow:

```
    scanf("%c", &ptr[i].gender);
    printf("Please enter Student %d's age.\n",i+1);
    scanf("%3d", &ptr[i].age);   //Only 3 digits can be put in at a time
    printf("Please enter Student %d's GPA.\n", i+1);
    scanf("%1lf", &ptr[i].gpa);
```